# Why was my post removed?

Tags: support, deleted-answer

I'm curious why you removed [my post on topic](https://superuser.com/questions/518218/file-corruption-after-copying-files-in-windows-7-64-bit-using-two-methods/619172#619172) "File corruption after copying files in Windows 7 64 bit using two methods". This was my first time posting to Super User, so I understand I may have done something inappropriate. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all this belongs on Meta.SU, which needs a mere 5 rep to post in. Anyway, it'll be migrated there. Next, can you link to your previous question?

Comment: You need 10k, but [link](http://superuser.com/a/619172/25625)

Comment: For information about the site, types of questions to ask, how to answer, etc., please browse through the [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help)

Comment: Having seen your deleted post, it was removed for good reason. You should read the Help pages and familiarise yourself with how this site works. It's mean to be strictly Q&A only. No lengthy back and forth discussions etc. since *this is **not** a forum*. If you had tested Photo Viewer more and confirmed it as the culprit, you could have focussed on that and it would have made for a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations. Sorry for being a total noob. I did some more tests which seem to confirm my suspicion, but I still don't know why it's happening. I will do some more tests and repost a question once I have some more understanding of what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

It was because you where asking a new question/making a extended comment as a answer to a existing question. You should have asked your own separate question or left it as a comment.

Comment: Not so much a question as a lengthy commentary/anecdote about how it happened to him as well. No real answer as such.

Comment: We expect answers to actually answer the question.